# Phoenix simple auth testing logged in user

Tags: authentication, elixir, phoenix-framework, ex-unit

From this [Simple authentication tutorial](https://medium.com/@andreichernykh/phoenix-simple-authentication-authorization-in-step-by-step-tutorial-form-dc93ea350153)

I am looking to test routes of the app inside the [`:login_required`](https://github.com/shouston3/phoenix_simple_auth/blob/master/web/router.ex#L18) pipeline (which simply checks if the client has called [`Guardian.Plug.sign_in(conn, user)`](https://github.com/shouston3/phoenix_simple_auth/blob/master/web/auth/auth.ex#L9))

As the `user_path` [`show`](https://github.com/shouston3/phoenix_simple_auth/blob/master/web/router.ex#L41) action needs to have been piped through the `:login_required` pipeline, I would have thought that to test this route I would simply need to write the following:

[`Auth.login_by_email_and_pass(conn, user.email, @password)`](https://github.com/shouston3/phoenix_simple_auth/blob/master/test/controllers/user_controller_test.exs#L32)

and then pipe the `conn` that comes out of that into:

`get conn, user_path(conn, :show, user.id)`

and check that I get a `200` status code.

But I can't get past the `Auth.login_by_email_and_pass(conn, email, password)` line and get the error:

`session not fetched, call fetch_session/2`

Where should I fetch the session?

I have tried `bypass_through(conn, [:browser, :with_session])`

I would have thought that the `:browser` pipeline invokes `fetch_session` which would have solved this issue.

I have also tried as calling `fetch_session` before and after, but still get the same error

Comment: Try calling `init_test_session/2`, like this: `conn = conn |> init_test_session(%{}) |> Auth.login_by_email_and_pass(user.email, @password)`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thank you, spot on, if you post an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Plug.Test.init_test_session/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Test.html#init_test_session/2) to initialize the session. Since you don't need to put any data, you can pass an empty map as the second argument.

```
conn = conn
  |> init_test_session(%{})
  |> Auth.login_by_email_and_pass(user.email, @password)
```